# How to validate Shopify Private App webhook using ShopifySharp

Tags: c#, webhooks, shopifysharp

I'm using [ShopifySharp](https://github.com/nozzlegear/ShopifySharp) to try and consume a Shopify order webhook as a Shopify Private App.

I can't get it to pass validation. My guess is the wrong secret key is being used.

Per ShopifySharp's [code](https://github.com/nozzlegear/ShopifySharp/blob/master/ShopifySharp/Services/Authorization/AuthorizationService.cs) (line 236):

`<param name="shopifySecretKey">Your app's secret key.</param>`

Per their Shopify Developer's Handbook, it states to use your app's secret:

```
var isValidRequest = await AuthorizationService.IsAuthenticWebhook(
Request.Headers.ToKvps(),
Request.InputStream,
ApplicationEngine.ShopifySecretKey);
```

My Code:

```
var isValidRequest = await AuthorizationService.IsAuthenticWebhook(
                Request.Headers.ToKvps(),
                Request.InputStream,
                shopifyPrivateAppSecretKey);
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally figured it out. In hindsight, this is rather obvious :)

For a *Private Shopify App*, you don't use *your* App's Secret, because there is no reference to that within the context of a Private App. In this case, you use the Shared Secret Key in the Private App settings in the actual Store:
[image]

For a *Public App* (which we're also in the process of developing, so things were getting confused), you use your app's API Secret Key in your Partner App settings:
[image]

Hope that helps someone else...or maybe I'm the only dull one to get this confused :)